# Getting sets of data from MySQL table with OFFSET and LIMIT when one set of data can come from 2 or more rows

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

Let's suppose I have a MySQL table 'orders' with the following data:

| id | order_no | item_id | amount | datetime            |
| 1  | 123      | 901     | 1      | 2020-08-05 00:00:01 |
| 2  | **324**      | 902     | 2      | 2020-08-06 00:00:01 |
| 3  | **324**      | 905     | 1      | 2020-08-06 00:00:01 |
| 4  | 511      | 902     | 1      | 2020-08-07 00:00:01 |
| 5  | 400      | 904     | 3      | 2020-08-08 00:00:01 |
| 6  | **195**      | 903     | 1      | 2020-08-09 00:00:01 |
| 7  | **195**      | 905     | 2      | 2020-08-09 00:00:01 |
| 8  | 250      | 908     | 1      | 2020-08-10 00:00:01 |
| 9  | 222      | 901     | 3      | 2020-08-11 00:00:01 |
| 10 | **315**      | 903     | 1      | 2020-08-12 00:00:01 |
| 11 | **315**      | 905     | 2      | 2020-08-12 00:00:01 |
| 12 | 198      | 903     | 1      | 2020-08-13 00:00:01 |
| 13 | **651**      | 902     | 2      | 2020-08-14 00:00:01 |
| 14 | **651**      | 907     | 2      | 2020-08-14 00:00:01 |
| 15 | 405      | 902     | 1      | 2020-08-15 00:00:01 |
| 16 | 112      | 905     | 1      | 2020-08-16 00:00:01 |

and in my website I want to display the orders according to user's settings like: orders per page/ page number. The data need to be ordered by 'datetime' in ascending order, so if the page number is 2 with orders per page = 5, I would need data of id-s 8-14 (as rows of id 1-7 make the first 5 orders and 8-14: the second one). Note that some orders (in **bold**) have 2 rows (and can have more) with the same order_no but different item_id.
The simple LIMIT and OFFSET clauses are of no use here unless I combine them with some subqueries but so far I have not found the solution.

Comment: The standard way to store orders (and any type of data with variable number of detailed line items) is to have two tables: a header table containing a single record for each order and a line item table containing the line items. With this setup, you could easily use the limit with offset.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Shadow I am aware of this approach but I thought it would be easier to have just one table, e.g. for deleting the order after the shipment complete; or for INSERT query with 2 items in one order - a single table would require 2 insert queries as opposed to 3, with 2 tables.

Comment: @Shadow Besides, the orders with only one item (as they're gonna be a majority) would only need one row in one table, one query to insert, update or delete, so I'm rather looking in the direction of a single table approach. Eventually, if I don't find a solution, I'd rather to get all orders (items) for the user and use some looping to filter the ones I need.

Comment: Yeah, normalisation means you have more tables, so potentially more insers and updates. However, your selects will be a lot simpler. In this particular case, you need to recreate the orders header table on the fly for this report to work. Is it worth for saving an extra insert?

Answer (score 0):

I have come to a solution that I think will work best for me: one table 'orders' with all the order 'header' data + first item of the order (each piece of item data in a separate column, like item_id, amount etc.) then, another column: 'items' of type JSON to store 2nd and further items if there are 2 or more; this way I'll be able to use LIMIT and OFFSET and will need only one query especially for inserting a new order, which had worried me the most because with 2 tables I would have to use a transaction.
A select query, in most cases will be simple, only with 2 or more items per order I will need to handle the items from the JSON column, it will not harm performance at all with, as I mentioned in a comment, most of orders containing only one item.
Thank you @Shadow for your comments, they have really helped me to find the solution as I think I'd been going in a wrong direction.